# Mid-range via minimax

Tags: references, central-tendency, minimax

<sub>**Warning:** [crossposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3817965/339790) at Mathematics SE.</sub>

---

Given vector ${\rm a} \in \Bbb R^n$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \displaystyle\arg\min_{x \in {\Bbb R}} & \left\| x {\Bbb 1}_n - {\rm a} \right\|_2^2\end{array} = \frac1n {\Bbb 1}_n^\top {\rm a} \tag{mean}$$

is the (arithmetic) **mean** of the entries of vector ${\rm a}  \in \Bbb R^n$, whereas

$$\begin{array}{ll} \displaystyle\arg\min_{x \in {\Bbb R}} & \left\| x {\Bbb 1}_n - {\rm a} \right\|_1\end{array} \tag{median}$$

is a **median** of the entries of vector ${\rm a}  \in \Bbb R^n$. Using the $\infty$-norm instead, what is the following?

$$\color{blue}{\boxed{\,\\\begin{array}{ll} \displaystyle\arg\min_{x \in {\Bbb R}} & \left\| x {\Bbb 1}_n - {\rm a} \right\|_{\infty}\end{array}}}$$

It appears to be the [mid-range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-range). I append a proof based on linear programming. Assuming that I have made no mistakes and my proof is indeed correct, I am interested in other **proofs** and in **references**.

---

#### My proof

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x \in {\Bbb R}}{\text{minimize}} & \left\| x {\Bbb 1}_n - {\rm a} \right\|_{\infty}\end{array} $$

Introducing optimization variable $y \in {\Bbb R}$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x, y \in {\Bbb R}}{\text{minimize}} & \qquad\qquad y\\ \text{subject to} & -y {\Bbb 1}_n \leq x {\Bbb 1}_n - {\rm a} \leq y {\Bbb 1}_n\end{array} $$

or, alternatively,

$$\begin{array}{lrl} \underset{x, y \in {\Bbb R}}{\text{minimize}} & y & \\ \text{subject to} & {\rm a} & \leq (x + y) {\Bbb 1}_n \\ & (x - y) {\Bbb 1}_n & \leq {\rm a}\end{array}$$

Let the entries of vector ${\rm a} \in \Bbb R^n$ be denoted by $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$. Note that there are many redundant inequalities:

- the set of $n$ inequalities ${\rm a} \leq (x + y) {\Bbb 1}_n$ can be replaced by $$x + y \geq \max \{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \}$$
- the set of $n$ inequalities $(x - y) {\Bbb 1}_n \leq {\rm a}$ can be replaced by $$x - y \leq \min \{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \}$$

Subtracting the latter inequality from the former inequality,

$$y \geq \frac{ \max \{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \} - \min \{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \} }{2} =: y_{\min}$$

and, thus,

$$ \begin{aligned} x &\geq \max \{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \} - y_{\min} = \frac{ \min \{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \} + \max \{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \} }{2} \\\\ x &\leq \min \{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \} + y_{\min} = \frac{ \min \{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \} + \max \{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \} }{2} \end{aligned} $$

Hence,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \displaystyle\arg\min_{x \in {\Bbb R}} & \left\| x {\Bbb 1}_n - {\rm a} \right\|_{\infty}\end{array} = \color{blue}{\frac{ \min \{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \} + \max \{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \} }{2}}$$

Some call this value the [mid-range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-range) of $\{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \}$.

Comment: It is difficult to reconcile your bounty request for "a canonical answer," which suggests you are expecting a single, objectively best approach, with your stated question, which explicitly is looking for "proofs" (*plural*) and "references" (also plural).  What, then, are you hoping to achieve with your bounty?

Comment: To compensate you for your effort. 30 points is not enough. You're welcome.

Comment: Thank you!  As you might guess from my previous comment, I wasn't expecting that to be your motivation -- I imagined you were hinting at a need for a completely different answer. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Graphical demonstration

[image: Figure]

*The components of vector $a$ are shown with blue ticks (a "rug plot"). $\tilde m$ is the midrange.  It occurs at the lowest possible value of the upper envelope of the graphs of the distance functions $x\to |x-a_i|,$ shown in red.*

#### 2. Elementary demonstration using number properties

This demonstration essentially explains the graph rigorously: it points out that the upper red envelope consists of two sloping arms meeting at the midrange.

**First let's set up some notation.**

This objective function is the maximum distance between the number $x$ and the set of components of $a$ (a subset of the real numbers).  Write $a_1$ for the least of those components and $a_n$ for the greatest. Let $\tilde m = (a_1+a_n)/2$ be their midrange, for which the maximum distance is $r = (a_n-a_1)/2.$

**Here, then, is the demonstration:**

> If $x \lt \tilde m$ then $|x-a_n| \gt r$ and if $x \gt \tilde m$ then $x-a_1 \gt r.$ Consequently, the only possible candidate to minimize the objective function is $\tilde m$ itself, *QED.*